# Why can I not Cast ServiceStack Ormlite Connection to SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlconnection, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to use `SqlBulkCopy` with `ServiceStack Ormlite` and have written the below extension method:

```
public static void BulkInsertSqlServer<T>(this IDbConnection dbConn, string targetTable, IEnumerable<T> data, params string[] columns)
{
  Ensure.NotNull(dbConn);
  Ensure.That(dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Open);
  Ensure.NotNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace(targetTable);
  Ensure.NotNull(data);
  Ensure.NotNullOrEmpty(columns);

  var sqlConnection = dbConn as SqlConnection;

  using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection))
  using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, columns))
  {
      bcp.BatchSize = data.Count();
      bcp.DestinationTableName = targetTable;
      bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
  }
}
```

Which I am using by:

```
_connFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connStr, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);

using (var db = _connFactory.Open())
using (var tran = db.BeginTransaction())
{
    db.BulkInsertSqlServer("User", users, "Name", "Age");

    var allRoles = new List<Role>();

    foreach (var listOfRoles in users.Select(d => d.Roles))
    {
        allRoles.AddRange(listOfRoles);
    }

    db.BulkInsertSqlServer("Role", allRoles, "Name", "UserId", "IsAdmin");

    tran.Commit();
}
```

However `sqlConnection` is always null, any ideas?

Comment: dbConnection doesn't seem to be declared anywhere. You have called "this" dbConn.

Comment: I can only suggest that it doesn't inherit from, neither is it a SqlConnection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the connection is wrapped in a managed [OrmLiteConnectionWrapper](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteConnectionWrapper.cs), you can get the SqlConnection with:

```
var adoNetConn = ((IHasDbConnection)dbConn).DbConnection;    
var sqlConnection = adoNetConn as SqlConnection;
```

Comment: Great, works like a charm, I wonder why you haven't added support for bulk loading to OrmLite? I can see many people who could benefit from this for both SqlServer and SQLite.

Comment: @MaYaN Development of new features are prioritized, [vote up this feature request](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/6429966-add-bulkinsert-bulk-copy-to-the-ormlite-databases) to register interest.

Comment: @mythz: With .NET 5.0, the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection type is being replaced with a new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection type. Will ServiceStack be supporting this new type? How can I extract a Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object from a repository's IDbConnection?